# Paraphrased lyrics 2

Tags: wordplay, music

A sequel to [Paraphrased song lyrics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62071/paraphrased-song-lyrics).

Each entry in the list below represents a paraphrase of lyrics from (hopefully) well-known songs. Identify the original lyrics, along with the song they occurred in and original performers.

> 1. Large, circular supports continually rotate, thereby transporting me to my relatives.
> 2. The pontificating cleric prefers his environment to have a relatively high derivative of entropy with respect to energy.
> 3. Your ivory-tower *moyen de vivre* based on communist ideology has proven to be a sham.
> 4. There are fewer than three atmospheric discharges (but greater than zero).
> 5. Exit the thoughts that were never verbalized, and reenact *William Tell*.
> 6. We missed you when we did drugs.
> 7. Over the course of twenty-four hours, I form a megahuman.
> 8. Every one of his utterances was unintelligible; nevertheless, I aided him with alcohol consumption.
> 9. Even though you do not share the moniker of a famous demon, I'm still cognizant of your goal.
> 10. That platform for pomposity has an impressive appearance.
> 11. Excessive attention to images transmitted through co-ax has induced me to pursue (figurative) REM sleep.
> 12. A portion of these people desire to be your exploiters, while another portion desire the reverse situation.
> 13. You broke up with me 1,321,200 seconds ago.
> 14. Based on my conscious stride, you should be able to deduce that I devote my attention to the opposite sex.  Therefore, conversation is
>       out of the question.
> 15. My vertical leap was sufficient for me to feel water vapor.

---

Hint on 3:

> More lyrics from the song: I suppose you're right when you tell me that under no circumstances could I ever be your type.

Hint on 7:

> More lyrics: Attempting to balance the budget puts you into bondage to specie — until your mortality manifests.

Comment: If one requires actual knowledge of the songs (i.e. have heard them before, more than once to be familiar with them) then you may wish to use the [tag:knowledge]. If these can simply be found by some internet searching then perhaps not. Looking over some of the answers I don't know many of these songs.

Comment: so this is basically un-verbose the lyric

Comment: Good job, everyone!  Now that all the lines have solutions, sometime later today I'll collect them into a community wiki - unless somebody else wants to do that before then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For the convenience of readers to find answers in one place:*

1. Large, circular supports continually rotate, thereby transporting me to my relatives.

> Big wheels keep on turning
>  Carry me home to see my kin.
>  — Lynyrd Skynyrd, "Sweet Home Alabama"
>  *Solved by Pugmonkey*

2. The pontificating cleric prefers his environment to have a relatively high derivative of entropy with respect to energy.

> You know the preacher like the cold.
>  — The Mamas and the Papas, "California Dreamin'"
>  *Solved by wolfram42*

3. Your ivory-tower *moyen de vivre* based on communist ideology has proven to be a sham.

> So much for all your highbrow Marxist ways.
>  — White Town, "Your Woman"
>  *Solved by Fillet*

4. There are fewer than three atmospheric discharges (but greater than zero).

> Lightning strikes maybe once, maybe twice.
>  — Fleetwood Mac, "Gypsy"
>  *Solved by Selene Ian*

5. Exit the thoughts that were never verbalized, and reenact William Tell.

> Come out of the things unsaid
>  Shoot an apple off my head.
>  — Cold Play, "Clocks"
>  *Solved by Fillet*

6. We missed you when we did drugs.

> Where were you while we were getting high?
>  — Oasis, "Champagne Supernova"
>  *Solved by Chowzen*

7. Over the course of twenty-four hours, I form a megahuman.

> But I'm a million different people from one day to the next.
>  — The Verve, "Bitter Sweet Symphony"
>  *Solved by Selene Ian*

8. Every one of his utterances was unintelligible; nevertheless, I aided him with alcohol consumption.

> I never understood a single word he said
>  But I helped him a-drink his wine.
>  — Three Dog Night, "Joy to the World"
>  *Solved by Pugmonkey*

9. Even though you do not share the moniker of a famous demon, I'm still cognizant of your goal.

> Mephistopheles is not your name
>  I know what you're up to just the same.
>  — The Police, "Wrapped Around Your Finger"
>  *Solved by Lord Farquaad*

10. That platform for pomposity has an impressive appearance.

> That's a fine looking high horse.
>  — Hozier, "Take Me to Church"
>  *Solved by wolfram42*

11. Excessive attention to images transmitted through co-ax has induced me to pursue (figurative) REM sleep.

> Too much television watching got me chasing dreams.
>  — Coolio, "Gangsta's Paradise"
>  *Solved by Selene Ian*

12. A portion of these people desire to be your exploiters, while another portion desire the reverse situation.

> Some of them want to use use
>  Some of them want to get used by you
>  — The Eurythmics, "Sweet Dreams"
>  *Solved by puzzledPig*

13. You broke up with me 1,321,200 seconds ago.

> It's been seven hours and fifteen days
>  Since you took your love away.
>  — Sinéad O'Connor, "Nothing Compares 2 U"
>  *Solved by Paul Parker*

14. Based on my conscious stride, you should be able to deduce that I devote my attention to the opposite sex. Therefore, conversation is out of the question.

> Well, you can tell by the way I use my walk
>  I'm a woman's man: no time to talk.
>  — The Bee Gees, "Stayin' Alive"
>  *Solved by puzzledPig*

15. My vertical leap was sufficient for me to feel water vapor.

> I jumped so high I touched the clouds.
>  — American Authors, "Best Day of My Life"
>  *Solved by puzzledPig*

Answer (score 9):

12:

> "Some of them want to use you / Some of them want to get used by you" or possibly "Some of them want to abuse you / Some of them want to be abused" - from Sweet Dreams, by the Eurythmics

14:

> "Well, you can tell by the way I use my walk / I'm a woman's man: no time to talk" - the first two lines of Stayin' Alive, by the Bee Gees

15:

> "I jumped so high I touched the clouds" - from Best Day of My Life, by American Authors

Comment: On 12 - it's the first.  VZB "rkcybvg" vf pybfre gb "hfr" guna "nohfr".

Answer (score 9):

5/ Exit the thoughts that were never verbalized, and reenact William Tell.

> Come out of things unsaid, shoot an apple off my head (Coldplay - Clocks)

3/ Your ivory-tower moyen de vivre based on communist ideology has proven to be a sham.

> So much for all your high brow Marxist ways (White Town - your woman)

Hint for 3:

> I suppose you're right when you tell me that under no circumstances could I ever be your type.

This translates to:

> Well I guess what you say is true, I could never be the right kind of girl for you,

Comment: I knew the hint for #3 but I couldn't look up the other lyric in time. Nice job!

Answer (score 9):

9.

> Mephistopheles is not your name. I know what you're up to just the same - Wrapped Around your Finger - The Police

Comment: (9) Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 8):

1. Large, circular supports continually rotate, thereby transporting me to my relatives.

> Sweet Home, Alabama by Lynyrd Skynyrd. --  Big wheels keep on turning; Carry me home to see my kin

8. Every one of his utterances was unintelligible; nevertheless, I aided him with alcohol consumption.

> Joy to the World by 3 Dog Night  --  I never understood a single word he said, but I helped him a-drink his wine.

Answer (score 8):

9 - Even though you do not share the moniker of a famous demon, I'm still cognizant of your goal.

> "So my intentions are known... Know me by name, Shepherd of Fire"
>  *Shepherd of Fire* by Avenged Sevenfold

13 - You broke up with me 1,321,200 seconds ago.

> "It's been seven hours and thirteen days / Since you took your love away"
>  *Nothing Compares 2 U* by Prince

Comment: 9 - not what I was thinking of, though I'm surprised at the fit.  I still think mine fits better.  13 - there's a minor error.  I would also have accepted Sinéad O'Connor as that part is just meant to provide some context, not to be tricky based on trivia.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I admit, I have never heard either of these songs before. I found them by googling lyrics with synonyms (e.g. "moniker" = name)       (1,321,200 seconds = 7 hours 13 days)

Comment: 1,321,200 seconds = 7 hours and 15 days.

Comment: @PaulParker You'd never heard of "Nothing Compares 2 U" before?

Comment: @Fillet Trivia tidbit. Prince wrote it with 13 days. Sinéad O'Connor changed it to 15.

Comment: I must have searched "7 hours and fifteen days," saw what the song was, then searched "Nothing Compares 2 U lyrics"

Answer (score 8):

7. "Over the course of twenty-four hours, I form a megahuman."

> "We can be heroes, just for one day"
>  *David Bowie – Heroes*

11. "Excessive attention to images transmitted through co-ax has induced me to pursue (figurative) REM sleep."

> "Too much television watching got me chasing dreams"
>
>  *Coolio – Gangsta's Paradise*

We're still missing (3) & (4), but I'm drawing blanks on those, although I feel like (3) should be obvious... Urgh.

Good puzzle though (& good songs too!)

EDIT: 
4. "There are fewer than three atmospheric discharges (but greater than zero)."

> "Lightning strikes, maybe once, maybe twice."
>  
>  *Fleetwood Mac – Gypsy*

Now that (3) is actively torturing me :p

EDIT²: Oh. I got 7 this time.

7. Over the course of twenty-four hours, I form a megahuman.

> "And I'm a million different people /
>  From one day to the next"
>  *The Verve – Bittersweet Symphony*

Here's the second hint:

> "Attempting to balance the budget puts you into bondage to specie — until your mortality manifests."

is

> "Trying to make ends meet / You're a slave to money then you die"

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the answer to 7 either.  (The original lyrics did indeed have first person singular, as opposed to the first person plural here, or the second person imperative from wolfram42's guess.)

Comment: I think I got 3 with the hint (see answer), bit annoyed at not getting 7, that was my Era

Answer (score 6):

6. We missed you when we did drugs.

> How many special people change?
> How many lives are living strange
> Where were you while we were getting high?
> -Champagne Supernova by Oasis

9. Even though you do not share the moniker of a famous demon, I'm still cognizant of your goal.
   Maybe its:

> Pleased to meet you
> Hope you guessed my name, oh yeah
> But what's puzzling you
> Is the nature of my game
> -Sympathy for the Devil by The Rolling Stones

11. Excessive attention to images transmitted through co-ax has induced me to pursue (figurative) REM sleep.

> I had the radio on, I was drivin'
> Trees flew by, me and Del were singin' little Runaway
> I was flyin'
> Yeah runnin' down a dream
> -Runnin Down a ***Dream*** (not Drain) by Tom Petty

Comment: 9 - nice guess, but doesn't quite fit.  11 - only fits half the clue.

Answer (score 5):

2.

> You know the preacher like the cold - California dreamin - Mamas and Papas

4. This could be a few different songs. I'll go with:

   > Strike! New York! Lightning!
   >  Not once but twice - Lightnin Strikes (not once but twice) - The clash

Runner up:

> Maybe lightning strikes twice - Lighting Strikes twice - Iron Maiden

7.

> Be a giant for a day - Giant for a Day - Gentle Giant

10

> That's a fine-looking high horse - Take me to Church - Hozier

Comment: 4 - on the right track, but neither is precisely what I was looking for.  7 - huh, hadn't heard of that one, otherwise I probably would have added something to distinguish it.  Not what I'm looking for, unfortunately.